# Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. * Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm developing a project and currently I'm stuck. The project loads on my android device and it was loading on my ios device but for the past week I cannot access the project on my ios.

I don't have a macbook so im using expo and casting to my phone to see app progress.

I dont know what to do anymore. The errors that I get are these

iOS Bundling complete 1772ms
ERROR  Invariant Violation: Your JavaScript code tried to access a native module that doesn't exist.

If you're trying to use a module that is not supported in Expo Go, you need to create a development build of your app. See https://docs.expo.dev/development/introduction/ for more info.
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.

`

```
index.js

`/**
 * @format
 */

import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);`


app.json
`
"expo": {
    "name": "Mapp",
    "slug": "Mapp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/MaAssets/images/Ma.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/MaAssets/images/Ma.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#000000",
      "animated": true
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
`



AppDelegate.m
`
NSDictionary *initProps = [self prepareInitialProps];
  UIView *rootView = RCTAppSetupDefaultRootView(bridge, @"Mapp", initProps);
```

`

Comment: did you rename your project.

Comment: @Engr.Aftab Ufaq..... I did not rename the project. I remembered testing one night. Everything was fine. Next morning, when I starting coding again one android it works perfectly fine and iOS it wasnt.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the android emulator.  Doing something similar might fix your problem.

I discovered that my old app was installed in my android emulator.  This fixed it for me:

1. I uninstalled both the app and the new app from the emulator.
2. I killed both Metro and the emulator.
3. I restarted both Metro and the emulator.

It turns out the emulator retains each app it installs instead of starting out as a blank slate each time as I expected. When it starts up, it tries to load the app with the earliest install time. So, it kept trying to run my old app and contact the old Metro server instead of running my new app.